# List<Rectangle> as a Property. Design mode will not allow to change the properties of Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

Using Microsoft Visual C#

I am making a Custom Control that has a list of Rectangles
I am creating the List like this

```
private List<Rectangle> _Rect = new List<Rectangle>();
public List<Rectangle> Rect { get { return _Rect; } set { _Rect = value; } }
```

In design mode when I add the Control to a form I cannot change the list.  in the properties window, I click on Rect which has a collection box.  the box opens allowing me to add new Rectangles, but where the properties of the rectangle are it says "Object does not match the target type"

It does work if I add a Rectangle as oppossed to a List.  And more complex properties work, ei. A list of custom class.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with how the `RectangleConverter` exposes a `Rectangle` for manipulation in the `PropertyGrid`.  For example, see the `Bounds` property on your control or form.  You can bypass this by creating a new `Rectangle` class that doesn't use the same `TypeConverter`, or you can switch to `RectangleF`, which does not use the `RectangleConverter`.

Comment: RectangleF solved my problems thanks alot.  It was the simpliest solution I could have hoped for.